# Webmatrix fails to create project from template

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webmatrix

I am using webmatrix2 and I can't create a project from template. It fails with an error

```
 Error

 There was an error creating site 'mysitename' Invalid Index.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070585)

 copy details to clipboard
```

while its 'downloading template from....' is being generated.
And here is my clipboard content

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
There was an error creating site 'mysitename'.

Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070585)
---------------------------
OK
---------------------------

---------------------------
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80070585): Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070585)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Interop.IAppHostElement.GetPropertyByName(String bstrSubName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.ConfigurationElement.GetAttributeValue(String attributeName)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_SslFlags()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.Binding.get_CertificateHash()
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(Binding binding)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.BindingCollection.Add(String bindingInformation, String bindingProtocol)
   at Microsoft.Web.Administration.SiteCollection.Add(String name, String bindingProtocol, String bindingInformation, String physicalPath, Byte[] certificateHash, String certificateStore, SslFlags sslFlags)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.CreateSiteHelper.CreateSite(String name, String path, FrameworkType frameworkType)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Utility.CreateSiteHelper.CreateSiteFromName(String name, Boolean makeNameUnique)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Gallery.Server.GalleryModuleService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<AddSiteFromName>b__f(ExecutionContext context)
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.Server.ModuleService.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.<InvokeOnMTA>b__0()
   at Microsoft.WebMatrix.Core.TaskServiceImplementation.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<InvokeOnMTA>b__5()
---------------------------
```

Have any of you experiencing this before an idea of what the error is meant ?

I have tried uninstalling webmatrix2 then reinstalling it but everything fails the same way. Thank you.

Comment: Yikes.  I'm passing this onto the WebMatrix dev team to take a look.

Comment: This looks like a problem with IIS Express.  Can you please try uninstalling IIS Express (all versions of it) and installing it again?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem but solved it by manually uninstalling IIS Express 7.5 and WebMatrix. Then I downloaded IIS 7.5, MSSQL Server Management Objects, and WebMatrix then installed it manually. My PC shutdown while installing through WebPI which may have caused the issue for me.

The links below are the ones I copied from WebPI:

IIS Express 7.5: http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/C/4/DC4EC38C-A6AA-449D-9B19-7ABC6DF72B34/iisexpress_1_11_x86_en-US.msi

MSSQL Server Management Objects: http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/E/D/FEDB200F-DE2A-46D8-B661-D019DFE9D470/ENU/x86/SharedManagementObjects.msi

WebMatrix 2: http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/5/7/8573745C-384B-4F74-BE2C-D85C390742D5/WebMatrix_x86_en-US.msi

Hope this helps.